# make new directories/folders based on contents of column

Tags: linux, shell

I need to make folders with data like the following.

the folder should be named uniquely based on column 1 eg. A,B,C,D
the contents of each folder should be the corresponding values in column 2

in addition i also want the total number of entries in each folder

eg. folder named "B" should have "B, B1 and B2" as differnt lines
number "3" as the total as the last line in folder "B"

DATA looks like :

```
col1    col2
A       A
B       B
B       B1
B       B2
C       C1
C       C2
C       C3
D       D1
D       D2
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First draw up a table that satisfies your conditions, i.e. the first item on each line to be the file name and the rest of that line to be the contents. This can easily be done by this awk command:

```
$ awk  '{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' q763074 | awk '{print $0, NF-1}'
A  A 1
B  B B1 B2 3
C  C1 C2 C3 3
D  D1 D2 2
```

(q763074 is your sample input)

Now pipe that output into this loop and you are done:

```
while read -r line; do
    #first item is the file name
    filename=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')

    #the rest is file contents
    content=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2-)

    # create file and and write each item to a new line
    echo "$content" | tr ' ' '\n' > "$filename.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "contents of the folder" - are those contents directories or files of some sort?  If directories this can be accomplished pretty easily with:

```
< /tmp/input.txt xargs -n2 bash -c 'mkdir -p $0/$1'
```

This says to send args two at a time from your input file (`/tmp/input.txt` in my example) to the trivial bash script `mkdir -p $0/$1`. Here, `mkdir -p` says to recursively make a directory with the first arg (`$0`) at the top level and the second arg below the first (`$1`).

If you wanted to make files instead of directories you can change this up to be like so:

```
< /tmp/input.txt xargs -n2 bash -c 'mkdir -p $0;touch $0/$1'
```

You can see what's going on by inserting `echo` in the command:

```
< /tmp/input.txt xargs -n2 bash -c 'echo mkdir -p $0;echo touch $0/$1'
mkdir -p A
touch A/A
mkdir -p B
touch B/B
mkdir -p B
touch B/B1
mkdir -p B
touch B/B2
...
```

Notice that the "`-p`" flag for `mkdir` is still needed so that `mkdir` doesn't fail if a dir already exists.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that's a simple tsv file, with zsh:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
table=/path/to/your/file.tsv

typeset -A seen failed entries
ret=0
warn() {
  print -rC1 -u2 -- "$@"
  ret=1
}

{
  read -r header_ignored
  while IFS=$'\t\t' read -r dir file rest_ignored; do
    # sanity checks
    if [[ $dir = /* ]]; then
      warn "skipping $dir absolute path"
    elif [[ -z $dir ]]; then
      warn "skipping empty dir"
    elif [[ /$dir/ = */../* ]]; then
      warn "skipping $dir with .. path components"
    elif [[ /$file/ = */../* ]]; then
      warn "skipping $file with .. path components"
    else
      file=${dir%/}/$file
      if
        [[ $file:h != . ]] &&
          (( ! seen[\$file:h]++ )) &&
          ! mkdir -p -- $file:h
      then
        (( fail[\$file:h]++ ))
        warn
        continue
      fi
      if (( ! fail[\$file:h] )); then
        if true >> $file; then
          (( entries[\$dir]++ ))
        else
          warn
        fi
    fi
  done
  for k v in "${(@kv)entries}"; do
    print -r -- $v entries were successfully created in $k
  done

  exit $ret
} < "$table"
```

(untested)

Note that if you have:

```
col1    col2
some/dir    subdir/file
./some/dir  subdir/file
some    dir/subdir/file
some/dir/subdir file
.   some/dir/subdir/file
```

for instance, it will not detect that it's the same file that is being "created" each time.